Nuxt 3 livechat plugin works on dev but not on production
I have a Nuxt 3 plugin a chat one the file name is chat.client.ts here is the script I have changed the url so that the company name wont be exposed. this code works fine when running on a dev mode but after building it fails
  const cssLink = document.createElement("link");
        cssLink.rel = "stylesheet";
        cssLink.href = "https://x.com/im_livechat/external_lib.css";
        document.head.appendChild(cssLink);

        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "https://x.com/im_livechat/external_lib.js";

        script.onload = () => {
            odoo.define("web.session", function (require) {
                const Session = require("web.Session");
                const modules = odoo._modules;
                return new Session(undefined, "https://x.com", { modules: modules, use_cors: true });
            });
            odoo.define("im_livechat.livesupport", function (require) {
                const rootWidget = require("root.widget");
                const im_livechat = require("im_livechat.legacy.im_livechat.im_livechat");
                const button = new im_livechat.LivechatButton(rootWidget, "https://x.com", {
                    header_background_color: "#4E6C62",
                    button_background_color: "#4E6C62",
                    title_color: "#FFFFFF",
                    button_text_color: "#FFFFFF",
                    button_text: "Chat",
                    input_placeholder: false,
                    default_message: "Hello, before we continue, can I please have your email address ?",
                    channel_name: "Main Chat",
                    channel_id: 1,
                    current_partner_id: 4,
                    default_username: "Visitor",
                });
                button
                    .appendTo(document.body)
                    .then(() => {
                        window.livechat_button = button;
                        // Ensure the button is properly appended before triggering the click
                        nextTick();
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Failed to append the livechat button:", error);
                    });
            });
        };
        document.body.appendChild(script);


here is the error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'static')

external_lib.js:3296 Undefined dependency:  web.Session
require @ external_lib.js:3296
(anonymous) @ BcV-9UXX.js:58
(anonymous) @ external_lib.js:3292
processJob @ external_lib.js:3292
odoo.processJobs @ external_lib.js:3300
odoo.define @ external_lib.js:3278
t.onload @ BcV-9UXX.js:58
load (async)
(anonymous) @ BcV-9UXX.js:58
iI @ BcV-9UXX.js:58
(anonymous) @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
r @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
runWithContext @ BcV-9UXX.js:14
sw @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
(anonymous) @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
run @ BcV-9UXX.js:10
runWithContext @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
rw @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
a @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
ow @ BcV-9UXX.js:18
await in ow (async)
Lp @ BcV-9UXX.js:63
(anonymous) @ BcV-9UXX.js:63
external_lib.js:3291 Error while loading web.session: r is not a constructor TypeError: r is not a constructor
    at BcV-9UXX.js:58:45150
    at external_lib.js:3292:63
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at processJob (external_lib.js:3292:9)
    at odoo.processJobs (external_lib.js:3300:1)
    at odoo.define (external_lib.js:3278:161)
    at t.onload (BcV-9UXX.js:58:45069)
...
external_lib.js:3296 Undefined dependency:  im_livechat.legacy.im_livechat.im_livechat

I have checked the sources the script is there, the network works the versions are same

Browser incompatibility maybe?

Nope, for sure, I have checked it )

They don't have a more "packaged" usage of their API? Without relying on inline scripts?

not for the version we are using, and updating will take a lot
